# Два действия при нажатии на кнопку в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть следующий код:

```py
class block_class:
    def create_block():
        global blocks_count
        block = PanedWindow(MainRoot, bg = 'blue')
        btn_DELETE = Button(block, text = 'X', command = lambda: block.destroy())
        btn_CONNECT = Button(block, text = 'Connect')
        entr_VALUE = Entry(block)
        block.pack(fill = NONE, expand = 0)
        block.add(btn_DELETE)
        block.add(btn_CONNECT)
        block.add(entr_VALUE)
        blocks_count += 1
```

Мне нужно чтобы при при нажатии на `btn_DESTROY` кроме удаления виджета так же происходило следующее действие - `blocks_count -= 1`
Я пробовал создать отдельную функцию, но из-за того что в блок создаётся в другой функции у меня не получилось.
Какими ещё способами можно добиться правильного результата?

Comment: понять зачем для метода def create_block(): нужен аргумент self, разобравшись в этом написать второй метод для кнопки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class BlockClass:
    def create_block(self):
        self.block_counts = 0
        self.block = PanedWindow(MainRoot, bg = 'blue')
        btn_DELETE = Button(block, text = 'X', command = self.destroyBlock)
        btn_CONNECT = Button(block, text = 'Connect')
        entr_VALUE = Entry(block)
        self.block.pack(fill = NONE, expand = 0)
        self.block.add(btn_DELETE)
        self.block.add(btn_CONNECT)
        self.block.add(entr_VALUE)
        self.blocks_count += 1
    def destroyBlock(self):
        self.block.destroy()
        self.block_counts -= 1
```